# "Unsupported Compiler" when setting Xcode compiler to gcc-6

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, openmp

As we know that OpenMP(not openMPI) is not supported by Clang now, so I installed gcc(6.2) by homebrew. What I want to do is use Xcode to run my OpenMP code, I changed the compiler from the default one(llvm clang) to :

```
Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C: gcc-6
```

in build settings.

but Xcode says: it's an "Unsupported Compiler". (I have set header path already)

Is there any way to make Xcode support Gcc6?

Xcode 8.0 in macOS Sierra